# What's the .Net Class for Proper Dialog Box

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to fire one without creating a Form and stuff.
Please help

Comment: Define "proper dialog box" and "fire".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simple, standard, *OK/Cancel* type dialogs, there's [`MessageBox.Show()`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show).

Comment: Thanks. Completely forgot about it